# Fulltext search with Simple.Data

Tags: orm, simple.data, micro-orm

I am trying out Simple.Data ORM. Is there a way take advantage of sql server's full text search with Simple.Data ORM? I found methods to use the wild card search but did not see anything for full text search. The wild card search is not very useful in my case because I have close to half a million rows to deal with.

I went through the
    [Simple.Data documentation](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/index.html) . I didn't see any mention of full text search.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Contains or Freetext as methods on a TEXT or NTEXT column, passing a string parameter, but there is no support for anything like FORMS OF; that's a bit too specific to SQL Server.

So:

var dubstepAlbums = db.Albums.FindAll(db.Albums.Description.Contains("dub-step"));

If that doesn't work, please [report it as a bug at the project Site](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/Issues).

Comment: I tried Contains and Freetext but none of them worked. I will put the ticket. The link appears to be broken. https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues  works.